# display form on mouse click on table elements using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, show

I am using jquery to do the following stuff-

I need to display the form right next to the table cell i click on, with some animation.

The problem with my code is that the form displays only once, and after that on any more mouse clicks it doesn't.

The code is-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("td").click( function(event) {
  var div = $("#myform");
  div.css( {
      position:"absolute", 
      top:event.pageY, 
      left: event.pageX});

  var delayTimer = setTimeout( function( ) {
        $that.fadeIn( "slow");
     }, 100);

  div.mouseover( function( event) {
     if (delayTimer)
         clearTimeout( delayTimer);
  }).mouseout( function(){
     if (delayTimer)
         clearTimeout( delayTimer);
     var $that = $(this);
     delayTimer = setTimeout( function( ) {
        $that.fadeOut( "slow");
     }, 500)         
  });
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table width="600" border="2" cellpadding="4">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="myform">
<form>
<input type="text" value="Arjun"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

more explanation---- 
on clicking any td cell, the div tag with id "myform" should display.. with animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setTimout` function refers to `$that` but you don't have such a thing in that scope:

```
var delayTimer = setTimeout( function( ) {
    $that.fadeIn( "slow"); // No $that exists here
}, 100);
```

I think you meant to say `div.fadeIn`:

```
var delayTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    div.fadeIn("slow");
}, 100);
```

You should also set `display: none` on `div` before you fade it in or the fade-in won't do anything:

```
div.css({
    position: "absolute",
    top: event.pageY,
    left: event.pageX,
    display: 'none'
});
```

And initialize it in your CSS:

```
#myform {
    display: none;
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/dWYfD/